# 6 Grams of Essential Amino Acids Post Workout on Keto Diet

Tags: weightlifting, protein, ketogenic-diet

I need this community's help to solve a problem that doesn't seem to have an answer that I can find online anywhere.

1. First, let it be known that I am following a ketogenic diet plan which disallows all sugars and (almost) all starches, which results in a very low daily carb count.  Virtually all of my carbs come from green leafy veggies (and other veggies).  What this means is that:
2. Eating a "protein bar" that has more than a trivial amount of carbs is not an option.
3. I recently read a book called "The New Rules of Lifting" in which the author asserts that in order to prevent muscle degradation (and actually promote muscle build up) after a weight lifting workout, one should consume "6 grams of essential amino acids" immediately after the work out. (Exactly how soon after I am not clear on, but that is the subject of a different question.)
4. Between the time that I lift my last weight, and the time that I can get home and cook a proper keto meal, at least 1 hour passes, sometimes more, depending on how bad traffic is that day.  What this means is that:
5. I need a convenient source of protein to consume after a workout that amounts to at least 6 grams of the essential amino acids without this source being a common protein/energy bar or a protein shake (both of which are usually very high in carbs).

What are my options?  Is there anyone on here that has faced this situation?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the "immediate" in "immediately after the work out", is always greatly exaggerated. Waiting 75 minutes instead of exactly 60 is not going to have an effect, there's tens of studies showing this, so feel free to look them up.

Second, most protein supplements, will usually specify the amount of BCAAs (branched chain amino acids) they provide. Generally this varies between 4-8g, which is pretty good. I'm not sure why you think these are high in carbs ? A protein supplement, on average, will have at most 3-5g of carbs, if that...and if that's a problem, there's tons that have 0 carbs, just go to a supplement store and look for yourself.

Third, you can just get the amino acids from a pure BCAA supplement. It will list how much of each amino acid is present. You can find these supplements at literally any supplement store like GNC, Popeyes, bodybuilding.com...etc, even at Walmart or Shoppers.

Fourth, 6 grams of essential amino acids is a bit over simplified, what you really need to focus on is at least 3 grams of Leucine , which is undoubtedly the most "essential" of essential amino acids, at least in terms of muscle building via its effects on the biosynthesis of protein. You can usually get that much leucine from 1-2 cans of tuna, or a few eggs.